# Unable to open .json file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, json

[image]

I want to convert a json file into a dataframe in pandas (Python). I tried with `read_json()` but got the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError:'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 21596351:character maps to <undefined>
```

I think I have some unwanted data in the json file like noise. The data is server generated.

This is a collection from the json file:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"57a30ce368fd0809ec4d1b41"},"session":{"start_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470151881189"},"session_id":"8356bd90-20160802-153121189"},"metrics":{},"arrival_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470152028294"},"event_type":"OfferViewed","event_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470151943271"},"event_version":"3.0","application":{"package_name":"com.think.vito","title":"Vito","version_code":"5","app_id":"7ffa58dab3c646cea642e961ff8a8070","cognito_identity_pool_id":"us-east-1:4d9cf803-0487-44ec-be27-1e160d15df74","version_name":"2.0.0.0","sdk":{"version":"2.2.2","name":"aws-sdk-android"}},"client":{"cognito_id":"us-east-1:1d507b8f-857c-42a4-a705-8db07d46bc8f","client_id":"aa092911-b9a7-498a-82da-76318356bd90"},"device":{"locale":{"country":"US","code":"en_US","language":"en"},"platform":{"version":"5.1.1","name":"ANDROID"},"make":"Xiaomi","model":"Redmi Note 3"},"attributes":{"Category":"90000","CustomerID":"4077","OfferID":"11846"}}
```

Comment: Have you tried to change the `encoding` option of `read_json()`? Default is `utf-8` and the character `0x81` (which is an A with an accent) cannot be read with this encoding option. I would give a try to some other options such as `encoding='iso-8859-1'` to see if it changes the error you get.

Comment: can you provide a valid JSON file?

Comment: their is some problem in my json file i just use a tool google open refine and change that file to csv and than load it in pandas using read_csv and it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read the file line by line, you can find a detailed answer in this [question of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088006/cant-figure-out-how-to-fix-the-error-in-the-following-code)

Comment: No, one doesn't have to (also, `lines` is deprecated in newer versions). It is sufficient to `data = pd.read_json(codecs.open(file_name, 'r', 'utf-8'))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import codecs
import pandas as pd
pd.read_json(codecs.open('json_file','r','utf-8'))
```

This should work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52879/discussion-on-answer-by-himanshu-rai-unable-to-open-json-file-in-pandas).

Comment: This is the correct answer actually.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.

```
import pandas as pd
#read line by line
with open('json_file','rb') as f:
  entries=f.readlines()
lines=list(entries)
Cleaned=[str(line).rstrip() for line in lines]
#Removes \n
Json="[" + ','.join(str(cl) for cl in Cleaned) + "]"

pd.read_json(Json)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52878/discussion-on-answer-by-himanshu-rai-unable-to-open-json-file-in-pandas).